# how can i hash a specific tag from XML file in a correct way?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, invoice, ubl

we are working on e-invoicing and to send the invoice to the government.

and they gave us what they want from us to do like signing some tags and hashing another.

my problem now is in hashing, when i hash the specific tag after doing every thing right and after that send it i get errors about hashing only.

and they gave us some samples, i took the sample and i took the tag that i face an error whan i hash it and try to hash it and compare it with its hash in the same file and i get different one , not the same.

i called them about this problem they said > you when you take the tag you are taking it in a wrong way.

the hash is : `sha256`

this is the invoice as XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"><ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
        <ext:ExtensionContent>
            <!-- Please note that the signature values are sample values only -->
            <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
                <sac:SignatureInformation>
                    <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                    <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                            <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>RvCSpMYz8009KbJ3ku72oaCFWpzEfQNcpc+5bulh3Jk=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                            <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>OGU1M2Q3NGFkOTdkYTRiNDVhOGZmYmU2ZjE0YzI3ZDhhNjlmM2EzZmQ4MTU5NTBhZjBjNDU2MWZlNjU3MWU0ZQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>MEYCIQDYsDnviJYPgYjyCIYAyzETeYthIoJaQhChblP4eAAPPAIhAJl6zfHgiKmWTtsfUz8YBZ8QkQ9rBL4Uy7mK0cxvWooH</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:Object>
                            <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2022-09-15T00:41:21Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                    <ds:DigestValue>YTJkM2JhYTcwZTBhZTAxOGYwODMyNzY3NTdkZDM3YzhjY2IxOTIyZDZhM2RlZGJiMGY0NDUzZWJhYWI4MDhmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382886904809774818644480820936050208702411</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
                            </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                        </ds:Object>
                    </ds:Signature>
                </sac:SignatureInformation>
            </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
        </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
    
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>SME00010</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>8e6000cf-1a98-4174-b3e7-b5d5954bc10d</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2022-08-17</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>17:41:08</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0200000">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note languageID="ar">ABC</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>10</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    
    
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">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</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference><cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
</cac:Signature><cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">324223432432432</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>الامير سلطان</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>3242</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:PlotIdentification>4323</cbc:PlotIdentification>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>32423423</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>الرياض | Riyadh</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>32432</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                    <cbc:CompanyID>311111111101113</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Acme Widget’s LTD</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName/>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>32423423</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName/>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">30.15</cbc:TaxAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">30.15</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">201.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">30.15</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cac:TaxCategory>
                 <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
                 <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                   <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
             </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">201.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">201.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">231.15</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">231.15</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">33.000000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">99.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
             <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">14.85</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">113.85</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>كتاب</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">3.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
               <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
               <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
               <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">3.000000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">102.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
             <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">15.30</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">117.30</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>قلم</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">34.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
               <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
               <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
               <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

and the specific tag that i need to take it in a correct way and hash it it is :

> xades:SignedProperties
> this is its ID:
> Id="xadesSignedProperties"

when i `hash` the tag and `encode` it into `base64` it needs to be same like this result:

> OGU1M2Q3NGFkOTdkYTRiNDVhOGZmYmU2ZjE0YzI3ZDhhNjlmM2EzZmQ4MTU5NTBhZjBjNDU2MWZlNjU3MWU0ZQ==

because it is the result in the sample.

---

what i have tried is:

i did a cancocalization on the XML file using `Python Code` after that i had taken the tag and took the hash of it and encode it into base64 and this is my Code:

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
import hashlib
import base64


et = ET.parse("sample_Invoice.xml")

et.write_c14n("my_xml_file.xml")


my_xml = open("my_xml_file.xml","rb")
my_xml_result = my_xml.read().decode()

# i will split the tag that is before <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
# to get the <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties"> and the rest
SignedProperties_1 = my_xml_result.split('<xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">')[-1]

# i will split the tag that is after <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
# to get the specific tag that i want only
SignedProperties_final = SignedProperties_1.split("</xades:QualifyingProperties>")[0]


# i will take the hash as hex
hashed_tag = hashlib.sha256(SignedProperties_final.encode()).hexdigest()

print(hashed_tag)

# i will encode the hex code into base64
print(base64.b64encode(hashed_tag.encode()))
```

this is my result:

> ZjcyZjUyNmFmYmY0ZGRmYWM2NDBlNzljYWVlZWNjOTM5ZjU4ZTY4ZTA3Y2JjM2Q0NzA4MzgwY2ZmOWM2ZTAzMw==

they are not the same at all.

i do not know what is the wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extracting the signed properties tag you need to add the namespaces declared in the ancestor elements to the root element of the document subset.

The signed properties tag should look like this:

```html
<xades:SignedProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2022-09-15T00:41:21Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                    <ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">YTJkM2JhYTcwZTBhZTAxOGYwODMyNzY3NTdkZDM3YzhjY2IxOTIyZDZhM2RlZGJiMGY0NDUzZWJhYWI4MDhmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">2475382886904809774818644480820936050208702411</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
```

Then you hash it with SHA256 and encode it with base64 normally.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the `{namespace}DigestValue` of the xml tag directly with `xml.etree.ElementTree` for hashing or base64 tranfermation:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import hashlib
import base64

tree = ET.parse("sample_Invoice.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}DigestValue":
        print("Parsed Value:",elem.text)
        key_val = f"{elem.text}".encode('utf-8')
        hashed_tag = hashlib.sha256(key_val).hexdigest()
        print("Hashed Value:",hashed_tag)
        b_hashed_tag = bytes(hashed_tag, 'utf-8')
        encoded = base64.b64encode(b_hashed_tag)
        print("Base64:", encoded)
```

Output:

```
Parsed Value: RvCSpMYz8009KbJ3ku72oaCFWpzEfQNcpc+5bulh3Jk=
Hashed Value: 142d6878757d5a715a4c4f446aaad8b20af682c0e6d759214c66561ca9ec17b6
Base64: b'MTQyZDY4Nzg3NTdkNWE3MTVhNGM0ZjQ0NmFhYWQ4YjIwYWY2ODJjMGU2ZDc1OTIxNGM2NjU2MWNhOWVjMTdiNg=='
Parsed Value: OGU1M2Q3NGFkOTdkYTRiNDVhOGZmYmU2ZjE0YzI3ZDhhNjlmM2EzZmQ4MTU5NTBhZjBjNDU2MWZlNjU3MWU0ZQ==
Hashed Value: f07791491ad0c69a0a75a8cfdcdd661985ee2867bb229cb57c9170a3f36f1a5d
Base64: b'ZjA3NzkxNDkxYWQwYzY5YTBhNzVhOGNmZGNkZDY2MTk4NWVlMjg2N2JiMjI5Y2I1N2M5MTcwYTNmMzZmMWE1ZA=='
Parsed Value: YTJkM2JhYTcwZTBhZTAxOGYwODMyNzY3NTdkZDM3YzhjY2IxOTIyZDZhM2RlZGJiMGY0NDUzZWJhYWI4MDhmYg==
Hashed Value: ac4a2ca13256a1e7967623f8f9103f156711d81afa7bda7e3e2bce4be4133063
Base64: b'YWM0YTJjYTEzMjU2YTFlNzk2NzYyM2Y4ZjkxMDNmMTU2NzExZDgxYWZhN2JkYTdlM2UyYmNlNGJlNDEzMzA2Mw=='
```

Hope I could help?

Comment: thank you for your time and your helps , but the answer that i was looking for was that answer under yours by **SarahMM** >>> and thanks again